# Order by result of a query / Mysql Subquery

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there (I'm new to PHP),

I can't quite figure out the syntax of a subquery I'm trying to make, this is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM show_episode, shows, show_episode_airdate, show_moyenne 
WHERE season = 1 AND episode = 1 
AND shows.imdb_id = show_episode.imdb_id_show 
AND show_episode_airdate.episode_id = show_episode.episode_id 
AND show_moyenne.show_id = shows.id 
AND show_episode_airdate.airdate < '2013-07-12' 
ORDER BY show_episode_airdate.airdate DESC LIMIT 10
```

Once this was done, I wanted to order those 10 selected rows by show_moyenne.moyenne with something like that:

```
SELECT * (FROM show_episode, shows, show_episode_airdate, show_moyenne 
WHERE season = 1 AND episode = 1 
AND shows.imdb_id = show_episode.imdb_id_show 
AND show_episode_airdate.episode_id = show_episode.episode_id 
AND show_moyenne.show_id = shows.id 
AND show_episode_airdate.airdate < '2013-07-12' 
ORDER BY show_episode_airdate.airdate DESC LIMIT 10) 
* ORDER BY show_moyenne.moyenne DESC
```

Which is not correct, anybody can show me the right way to do this ?

Thanks, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT x.* 
   FROM
      ( SELECT * 
          FROM show_episode e
          JOIN shows s
            ON s.imdb_id = e.imdb_id_show 
          JOIN show_episode_airdate a
            ON a.episode_id = e.episode_id 
          JOIN show_moyenne m
            ON m.show_id = s.id 
         WHERE season = 1 
           AND episode = 1 
           AND a.airdate < '2013-07-12' 
         ORDER 
            BY a.airdate DESC 
         LIMIT 10
      ) x
  ORDER 
     BY moyenne;
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, thanks!
Although, I get duplicated column episode_id error ?

Comment: Don't use "SELECT *". Name the columns you actually want returned.

Comment: I don't understand what x represents ? I should specify the columns I want returned in the inner query ?

Comment: Yes - or both... and try it without the 'x'

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'moyenne' in 'order clause' now ?!

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from 
(SELECT * FROM show_episode, shows, show_episode_airdate, show_moyenne 
WHERE season = 1 AND episode = 1 
AND shows.imdb_id = show_episode.imdb_id_show 
AND show_episode_airdate.episode_id = show_episode.episode_id 
AND show_moyenne.show_id = shows.id 
AND show_episode_airdate.airdate < '2013-07-12' 
ORDER BY show_episode_airdate.airdate DESC LIMIT 10) as j 
order by j.moyenne DESC
```

I hope this can be of some help.